# Saving to new txt file each time library saved by user

Tags: java, text, output

How would it be possible to enable my application to save to a new .txt file each time the user wishes to save, as opposed to overwriting the existing one?

I have this code which functions and saves information to a text file:

```
            if(Menu.menuChoice == 1 && Library.ManualList.size() > 0){                      
                Library.displayManualList();
                boolean saveYesNo = Console.readYesNo("The ManualKeeper® app is able to save your current library to a '.txt' \nfile in your workspace directory.\n\nWould you like to save the current library? (Y/N):\n");
                if(saveYesNo){
                    try {
                        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Library.txt");
                        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

                        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < Library.ManualList.size(); i1++){
                            pw.println("-------------------- Index Number: " + i1 + " --------------------");
                            pw.println(Library.ManualList.get(i1).displayManual());
                            pw.println("---------------------------------------------------------\n");
                        }
                        pw.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("Error! Library unable to save.");
                    }
                    System.out.println("\n\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("\n                              Library saved!\n");
                    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                }
                    else if(saveYesNo){
                        System.out.println("\n");
                }
```

Ideally I would like the files to be saved in a numbered fashion, so the user could easily select which .txt file to view, at a later date.

Comment: Couldn't you simply add an integer to the end of the filename?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save it to a new file each time, the file name has to be unique.

You can achieve this in mulitple ways. Some ideas:

### Date+Time in file name

Add the current date+time to the file name, this will also be informative as when it was created/saved, and when listing files, newer files will be at the end of the list naturally.

```
String name = "Library-"
    + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss").format(new Date()) + ".txt";
```

As an alternative, you could simply append [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--) which will preserve natural creation order but will not be as nice looking/informative:

```
String name = "Library-" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".txt";
```

### Random String in file name

This might not be as nice looking, but for example:

```
String name = "Library-" + UUID.randomUUID() + ".txt";
```

### Counter in the file name

The idea is to use a counter in the file name, so the first should be `"Library.txt"`, the next should be `"Library (2).txt"`, the third should be `"Library (3).txt"` etc.

For this to implement, we have to check existing files to determine the next value of the counter. Here is an example how to do it. This is not optimal, but does the job:

```
public static Path uniqueFile() {
    Path file = Paths.get("Library.txt").toAbsolutePath();
    if (!Files.exists(file))
        return file;

    Path folder = file.getParent();

    for (int counter = 2; true; counter++) {
        file = folder.resolve(String.format("Library (%d).txt", counter));

        if (!Files.exists(file))
            return file;
    }
}
```

And using it:

```
String name = uniqueFile().getFileName().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the application is made with a GUI, a fileDialog would be best (save if he wants to override the file, save as if he wants to save it to a new file, like a lot of applications have).

In your case you should use a counter and add it to the end of the file like Library1.txt.
If rerun the application, of course this counter variable is reset resp. it is not stored. I would suggest to store this variable (and other attributes like that) in another file, e.g. config.txt

This config.txt file you can read (and parse it like I showed you in a previous answer). So everytime you start your application you read the config.txt file, set the counter. Before exiting the application of course you have to save the counter to the config.txt file.

**Just pseudocode:**

```
//load at start of application
counter = loaded from config.txt
//save to a new file

FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Library" + counter++ + ".txt");

//save counter to config.txt file
```